# Why are cost effectiveness studies published?

Tags: public-health

I'm new to the field of health technology assessment and have been reviewing and doing cost effectiveness analysis of different proposed technologies in a academic context over the past couple of months. I cant help but wonder sometimes why such situation specific results are worth publishing.

Why are cost effectiveness analyses worth publishing and how are these results generalizable to situations where the clinical pathway may differ?

Note: I have no background in medicine but I support research projects as a health economist on a mostly clinical based team.

Edit: my main concern is surrounding studies like [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/figure/10.1080/20016689.2021.1966187?scroll=top&needAccess=true) where the clinical and cost based considerations may differ across different countries. Hence the cost effectiveness of a technology in on circumstance is not the same as another.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... Surely an economist can see why a costs are relevant?

Comment: @Bryan_Krause i see why costs are relevant. Just that the results that are published in most cost effectiveness are in a very particular set of circumstances. Id assume if something is published, its for general scientific readership. Given the specicifity of the results I dont know how they are generalizable.

Comment: @EconJohn If only perfectly generalizable studies were published in medicine, there would be nothing to put in any medical journals but ads and perhaps letters to the editor wondering why there are no papers published. A good study should have its methodology well-described, and it's up to the reader to decide from there how much they can take from what is published and what they need to do on their own or create by combining multiple sources.

Comment: @BryanKrause as a non clinician I appreciate this comment. Thank you!

Comment: For clarity, I'm not a clinician either, just the "other" kind of doctor with a science background. :)